# How to use LabVIEW to control and command Keithley 2410 - 2400 Source meter

Tags: python, labview, visa, pyvisa, gpib

Trying to connect Keithley 2410 Source meter from GPIB port and command and control its current frequency change for my setup. I need to use SCPI I guess. how can I do that is there any one help me with that SCPI visa transformation appropriate way to command to Keithley 2410 lab equipment via Python or LabVIEW.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use LabVIEW Instrument Drivers. Luckily, there are drivers which you need - http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.download_page?p_id_guid=25B255F3AA83660EE0440003BA7CCD71.
Also, more general information you could find here: https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000x3XpCAI.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, i came across with them in my research in google but I am not sure I can write the code for current frequency and modulation  due to lack of knowledge that I have in scpi. i checked the keitleys user manual scpi part its too difficult to get to me

Answer (score 0):

There´s no other way as to do this with SCPI commands. Especially LabView offers different ways (generic ones as well as described from @kosist) - but more complex settings are only to solve by understanding SCPI commands and provide them via write commands. I would give them a trial - it´s  less complicated as you think.

Important is, that you use waiting times (e.g. 100 ms) between write and read commands. If you directly try to read out after write it could be, that you read nothing in the resulting dataframe. Also take a look in needed delimiters of the commands, if you use the generic GPIB way.